# How to get a particular element from a customized struct data in c++?

Tags: c++

Now I have :

```
struct vote
{
  int user; // ID of the user
  int item; // ID of the item
  float value; // Rating
};

typedef struct vote vote;
```

And testVotes iterates this data type:

```
std::set<vote*> testVotes;
```

Given the testVotes pointing to the vote data contains the information that a certain user give a certain rating to a certain item. Now I want to get the items which the user, let's say, the first user(user id =1) has not rated yet.

In addition, as this code is written by others, and there has been thousands of lines already, I do not prefer to change the existing struct. How can I do what I want without changing the existing code?

Thank you in advance!

------------------------------new demand-----------------------------------

given a known element user id, 3, and another known element item id, 5, how can I get the corresponding element value (3, 4, ?) ?

Comment: 3 has rated item 5 with 4.0

Comment: BTW, in C++ you don't need the `typedef`.  Use the structure name.

Comment: Do you need a set of *pointers* or will a `std::set<vote>` work?  I think the pointer is causing an issue (you presently have a set of pointers, not a set of votes).

Comment: I recommend splitting the key (`user`) from the `struct vote` and using `std::map<int, vote>` where the `int` represents the user number.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks for your reply! I defined typedef in .hpp file. And I do not prefer to change the existing struct as there has been thousands of lines already. How can I do this by adding new code?

Comment: Your question is very unclear and perhaps too broad.

Comment: Sorry @BasileStarynkevitch, I am totally new to c++, could you please tell me which part is unclear so that I can improve it.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do in the details (and I guess you don't understand neither).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Given the testVotes pointing to the vote data contains the information that a certain user give a certain rating to a certain item. Now I want to get the items which the user, let's say, the first user(user id =1) has not rated yet. Is it clearer?

Comment: Please **edit your question** don't comment it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If looking for the solution for a single specific user a function could build an `std::set` of all items that him/her rated:

```
std::set<int> rated_items(int user) {
    std::set<int> result;
    for (auto p : testVotes) {
        if (p->user == user) result.insert(p->item);
    }
}
```

however if you need to do this for all users then building a single map from users to rated items would be more efficient:

```
std::map<int, std::set<int>> rated_items() {
    std::map<int, std::set<int>> result;
    for (auto p : testVotes) {
        result[p->user].insert(p->item);
    }
}
```

Knowing which items a user rated makes trivial to know which items the user has NOT rated.

PS: the data structure `std::set<vote *>` looks a **very** questionable choice (a `std::set<vote>` would seem much more reasonable, or an `std::vector<vote>` if the same user can rate the same item multiple times).
Thousands of lines already written is nothing compared to the grief of living **forever** with a bad data structure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! The code above is the source code of a recommendation engine by a professor. I am not working with him and I just want to do some experiment using his code. I don't know why he wrote it like this. But I guess, given there are two more similar pointers:
    std::vector<vote*> trainVotes;
    std::vector<vote*> validVotes;
Maybe he wanted to point different part of the dataset so he got a dataset for training, another part for testing and the other part for validation.

Comment: @yobichi: using a pointer may make sense if he wanted to reference the same "vote" object from multiple containers (for example to update it and having all containers seeing the updated vote). Probably a naked pointer won't be the first choice in modern C++ because it's quite dangerous (smart pointers are normally preferred) but it's also possible that the choice is indeed good (as usual with IT the only real answer is "it depends").

Comment: I wonder why the rated_items should be here? I think the map result has already contained the user and the corresponding items rated by him, like <user 1, <item1, item3, item50> >.

Answer (score 0):

You really should spend several days to read much more about [Programming using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html) and about [C++ standard containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container).

You might have some map or set indexed by user ids (e.g. have some appropriate `class userdata` then use `std::map<int,userdata>` and/or `std::set<int>`  with the `int` key being the `user` id).

Contrarily to your claims, if you are working in a team, you should consider (after discussion with co-workers) to improve the data structure and the existing code (so patching the `struct vote` *should* be discussed and attempted, and you should consider patching the code at other places too!). A version control system like [git](http://git-scm.com/) facilitate doing that.

Perhaps you should use [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer), for example by declaring `std::set<std::shared_ptr<vote>> testVotes;` or you just want a set of votes `std::set<vote> testVotes;`

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Actually, I am not working in a team. I am studying recommender system. The code above is the project by a professor from Stamford and he stated a new way for recommendation. I am trying to evaluate this approach from the perspective of top-n recommendation.